# Moving Infopath Document Information Panel from one SharePoint Document Library to another

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

My colleague and I are unable to move our Document Information Panel from one document library to another document library on a different site collection. Both document libraries have the same fields/columns and are exactly the same except that they are on different site collections. We have tried using "Convert Data Source" and "Change Bindings" from within Infopath, then publishing the DIP to the SharePoint document library, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll be back to confirm this later but it seems like it only works when the Infopath part is done on the SharePoint server. If it is done from another machine w/ Infopath installed that's when I'm having issues. Funny how I spend 2 days figuring this out but as soon as I give up and post on SO, I come to that realization in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Convert main data source" from within InfoPath on the SharePoint server. Do not attempt to do it from another server or workstation. After converting the main data source, publish the document information panel to the SP document library.